# removing first occurrence of a character in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a column with values as below:

```
BOOK # ,7,8
BOOK # ,2
BOOK # ,13,14
```

I am generating above column with complex xml aggregate function as below:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('BOOK # ',XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(CONCAT(',', SUBSTR(TRIM(TEMP.BOOK_NUM),    
LOCATE('.',TEMP.BOOK_NUM)+1)))) AS VARCHAR(1024 )))
FROM TEMP 
GROUP BY BOOK_ID
```

Temp.book_num is of type 123.2, 123.4 in two different rows. So book_id 123 will have two books 2, 4. Thus to extract 2 and 4 out of two rows of same book_id, I had to write above query.

As clear there is an extra ',' comma coming after the words 'BOOK #' which is redundant and unrequired.

I am not able to modify above query to remove it.

Is there any way possible to remove the first occurrence of a character (comma here) from a column value which could be accomodated in the query above ?

My output should be:

```
BOOK # 7,8
BOOK # 2
BOOK # 13,14
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the wording is almost identical, it's a lot easier to remove the first character than it is to remove the first occurrence of a specific character. Fortunately, just removing the first character will solve your problem. You can do that by stuffing your `XMLSERIALIZE()` expression into a `SUBSTR()` call like this:

```
CONCAT('BOOK # ',
    SUBSTR(
        XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(CONCAT(',', SUBSTR(TRIM(TEMP.BOOK_NUM),  
           LOCATE('.',TEMP.BOOK_NUM)+1)))) AS VARCHAR(1024))
       ,2
    )
)
```

Thanks to Serge Rielau for posting this trick in his [blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/aggregating_strings42?lang=en_us).

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use [REPLACE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000843.htm) function.

Replace 'BOOK # ,' by 'BOOK # '.

Comment: Your solution works in the case presented. However, is there a solution specific to what I have asked - Replacing the first occurrence of a given character. Replace may not work in every such requirement.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan possibly exists but I don't know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE (colname , (SUBSTR(colname ,1 ,LOCATE(',',colname)-1)) , (SUBSTR(colname ,1 ,LOCATE(",",colname)-1))|| ' ') from *sometable*
```